# Angular Manejo de peticiones http

Tags: angular, http

Buenas para todos mi inquietud es cómo podría lograr que varias peticiones a un servicio rest se ejecuten de manera secuencial cuando una termine si todo a ido bien continúe con la siguiente esto debido a que requiero la respuesta de una petición para enviarle los datos correspondientes a la siguiente he pensado en introducir dentro del suscribe la petición siguiente pero me parece q no sería la mejor práctica y debería existir una mejor manera de llevar a cabo está tarea 
Muchas gracias a todos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Puedes realizar el proceso con el **await** y el **async**. Te dejo el siguiente servicio como ejemplo:*

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EjemploService {

  private url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/titulos';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public getTitulo1(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url);
  }
  
  public getTitulo2(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url);
  }
}
```

*Ahora vamos a ejecutar ambos servicios, retornarán lo mismo pero los separé así para que veas que se puede implementar como lo que deseas.*

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EjemploService } from '../ejemplo.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ejemplo',
  templateUrl: './ejemplo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ejemplo.component.css']
})
export class ejemploComponent implements OnInit {

  private titulo: string;

  constructor(private ejemploService: EjemploService) { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
     this.getTitulo();
  }

  private async getTitulo() {
    await this.ejemploService.getTitulo1().toPromise().then(titulo => this.titulo = titulo);
    console.log('titulo 1', this.titulo);

    await this.ejemploService.getTitulo2().toPromise().then(titulo => this.titulo += ' ' + titulo);
    console.log('titulo 2', this.titulo);
  }
}
```

*Como puedes observar ejecuto ambos servicios sin estar uno dentro del otro, dado que ambos servicios retornan un observable, para que el **async** con el **await** tengan el efecto esperado, se deben tratar como promesas, dicho esto se cambia el **.subscribe()** por el **.toPromise().then(...)**, agregamos unos **console.log** para que veas el orden como imprime.*

*de igual manera te dejo el link donde puedes observar a mas profundidad el **async** y el await*: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona

*Espero haber sido claro.*

Comment: muchas gracias por tu rápida respuesta, algo como esto era lo que buscaba, aun no lo he intentado  pero ya lo haré y  estaré pasando a comentar como me ido.

Comment: @AndresOspino Dale, comentas como te va

Comment: Esa fue la la solución el proceso se ejecutó perfectamente muchas gracias 